# When to use `source()` or `attach()`

Tags: r, project-management, workflow

Part of my project directory structure looks like:

```
\projects\project\main.R
\projects\project\src
```

where `\src` contains a bunch of 1-function-per-file, project-specific functions.

Q: What's the best practice way to add these functions to the working directory `projects\project`?

There are a few solutions I see:

1. `attach("./src")`. I'm trying to avoid this because (1) the Google Styleguide recommends avoiding the use of `attach()` and (2) I receive the

   ```
   Warning messages:
   ```

   `1: Reading Unix style database directory (./tmp) from Splus on Windows: may
       have problems finding some datasets, especially those whose names
       differ only by case (file tmp-script1.ssc should not have been made by
       Splus on Windows) in: exists(name, where = db)`
   when doing this.
2. `lapply(paste("./src/",list.files("./src/"),sep=""),source)`. This works perfectly fine, it just seems clunky. There has to be a better way, right?
3. Refer to my functions by their full name `./src/myfunc`. This will get ugly very quick. I'm sure there's a better way.
4. Get rid of the `./src` part of my directory and just throw all the functions in the main working directory. The problem with this is that I'd prefer to keep with a directory structure that is close to that of John Myles White's `ProjectTemplate`
5. Throw all the functions in one file, `./src/func.R` and source that. I guess this approach avoids the ugliness of "2." above, but I'd really like to have one function per file. Just seems cleaner that way.

Comment: I think this question is off-topic because it has nothing to do with statistical analysis.  SO looks like a more appropriate venue where you might get quick useful answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
lapply(list.files("src", full.names = TRUE), source)
```

**EDIT**

or

```
lapply(Sys.glob("src/*"), source)
```

Comment: @G: Is this what people generally do in their R projects? If this were Splus one could just `attach()` the directory and be done. Doesn't seem like there's a simple equivalent in R.

Comment: R packages are frequently used.  If you just want to run off plain files then have one file which sources all the rest.  Then you only have one file to directly `source()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to put everything into a local package, then I'd go for option 2.